# Solr reference not return data

Tags: solr, doc

I followed the steps in below official doc, and it does not work when I search by a term.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-techproducts.html

Below curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=foundation" return empty result.

can anyone help what was the reason?

Comment: Do you find any documents if you search for `*:*`? Do you find any documents if you give a field name? (`series_t:foundation` or `series:foundation` iirc).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I used the default schema which does not have copy fied